# How to decrease the runtime that Excel VBA takes when executed from a Visual Basic Net application?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, runtime, vba

Software used:
**Visual Basic Net 2013** ,
**Microsoft Excel 2016**

I have a problem when executing a code directly from the VBA Excel editor compared to the time required to execute the same VBA from Visual Basic Net code. Even if I code a simple

```
Sub myCode()
   MsgBox "Hello World!", vbOkOnly
End Sub
```

in VBA, it takes too much time to start the execution when I execute from Visual Basic code.

For example, when I press 'F5' key in VBA editor, it takes less than one second to execute the code and show the MsgBox. When I run exactly the same code from Visual Basic .Net, it takes around 30 seconds to start executing the code.

The code I am using in Visual Basic is the following one:

```
Private Sub executeExcelMacro(ByVal filePath As String, ByVal macroName As String)
        Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
        Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet

        oExcel = New Excel.Application
        oExcel = CType(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
        oBook = GetObject(filePath)
        oSheet = oBook.Worksheets("TestExcel")
        oSheet.Activate()
        oBook.RunAutoMacros(1)
        oExcel.Run(macroName)
End Sub
```

The idea is to have an Excel file opened in Excel 2016 and update automatically its content using the VBA code, so I can see how a new row is created each time the VBA code is automatically executed from Visual Basic .Net

Comment: But you do not run exactly the same code.

Comment: Hi Storax, in this question I show the code I finally run. But I have run the Hello World code directly from VBA and from VB.Net and it takes around 30 seconds to run if I try to execute the Hello world from VB.Net. I don't know what is causing to slow down the execution of any VBA code if I launch it from VB.Net. Once the VBA starts, it takes the same time to complete the tasks. The problem is between VB.Net tries to execute the VBA code and the execution of the VBA code starts. It takes around 30 seconds and I don't know why.

Comment: Sorry, but IMO your code cannot run at all because you start a new instance of excel and try to assign it to itself and then you assign `obook`to a new instance. The line `oexcel.run` should throw a run time error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following VB.NET code is running fine and fast at my computer

```
Private Sub executeExcelMacro(ByVal filePath As String, ByVal macroName As String)
    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    oExcel = New Excel.Application
    oExcel.Visible = True
    'oExcel = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
    'oBook = GetObject(filePath)
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets("TestExcel")
    'oSheet.Activate()
    'oBook.RunAutoMacros(1)
    oExcel.Run(macroName)
    oBook.Close(False)
    oExcel.Quit()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Performing some tests, the following code is the fastest I have found:

Dim ExcelAPP As Excel.Application
ExcelApplication = CType(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
ExcelApplication.Run(macroName)